# How to get the twitter URL and linkedin URL for a company?

Tags: php, parsing, twitter, linkedin-api, semantics

I've got a list of company names, like:

```
AB Electrolux
ABB Ltd
Kingfisher PLC
```

For each company in the list, I need

```
company's twitter URL
company's Linkedin URL
```

Is there an API service that does that in an automated fashion? Maybe a combination of various services could work?

Or Is it possible to parse the result from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter links for know companies are same as their names like @Electrolux for electrolux, you can create an array of these ids and check from twitter api at https://dev.twitter.com/ whether it returns true or false.